# How to delete outliers on linear scatter plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, error-handling, outliers

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
```

I want to delete the outliers outside of the green lines from my data. My actually data is in a data frame and there are a lot of outliers. It would also be helpful to scale the width of the green lines for larger values of x.

```
x = [1,1.1,2,3,4,5,5.5,6,7,8,9,10, 10.10]
y = [1,0.1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,9,10, 16]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)),
               columns =['x_vals', 'y_vals'])

plt.scatter(df.x_vals,df.y_vals)
z = np.polyfit(df.x_vals,df.y_vals, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
z = plt.plot(df.x_vals,p(df.x_vals),"r--")
z_1 = plt.plot(df.x_vals,p(df.x_vals) + 1,"g--")
z_2 = plt.plot(df.x_vals,p(df.x_vals) - 1,"g--")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just filter them as in (Pseudo): `(x, y)` => `y >  p(x) + 1` or `y < p(x) - 1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the outliers as the points for which the y-value is either larger than the upper limit or smaller than the lower limit.

The following code example encircles the leftover points in purple, and crosses out the outliers.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

###import math

x = [1, 1.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10.10]
y = [1, 0.1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)),
                  columns=['x_vals', 'y_vals'])

plt.scatter(df.x_vals, df.y_vals)
z = np.polyfit(df.x_vals, df.y_vals, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
z = plt.plot(df.x_vals, p(df.x_vals), "r--")
delta = 1
z_1 = plt.plot(df.x_vals, p(df.x_vals) + delta, "g--")
z_2 = plt.plot(df.x_vals, p(df.x_vals) - delta, "g--")
plt.fill_between(df.x_vals, p(df.x_vals) - delta, p(df.x_vals) + delta, color='g', alpha=0.1)

outliers = df[(df.y_vals < p(df.x_vals) - delta) | (df.y_vals > p(df.x_vals) + delta)]
cleaned = df[(df.y_vals >= p(df.x_vals) - delta) & (df.y_vals <= p(df.x_vals) + delta)]

plt.scatter(cleaned.x_vals, cleaned.y_vals, s=100, fc='none', ec='purple')
plt.scatter(outliers.x_vals, outliers.y_vals, marker='x', s=200, fc='none', ec='r')

plt.show()
```

[image: identifying outliers]